# How can I execute JavaScript function when the enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I just learnt web-dev 4 months ago and my first real project is a calculator and long story short, I want to display the result of a calculation when the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Here's my code:

```
var keyInput = function(e) {
    var eventObject = window.event ? event : e;
    var code = eventObject.charCode ? eventObject.charCode : eventObject.keyCode;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(code);
    if (!isNaN(Math.min(key))) {
        displayEntry(key);
    } else if (key === "/") {
        enterOperation("÷");
    } else if (key === "*") {
        enterOperation("×");
    } else if (key === "-") {
        enterOperation("-");
    } else if (key === "+") {
        enterOperation("+");
    } else if (key === "%") {
        enterOperation("%");
    } else if (unicode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        displayResult('=');
    } else if (key === "c") {
        clearDisplay();
    }
};

document.onkeydown = keyInput;
```

It all works apart from <kbd>enter</kbd> (`unicode === 13`). What am I doing wrong? And why is the <kbd>enter</kbd> key printing the `\n` character even though there are no text fields on the page?

Comment: you've just made a mistake in your code - you have no variable "unicode"! That should probably be else if(key === 13)

Comment: There is no `unicode`, it's named `code`?

Comment: I've changed "unicode" to "code", but it still won't work. I've been stuck on this for days. I'm so frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set unicode... The \n is added because it's the newline character added when you press enter. if you don't want it, you might want to remove the last character added.